# Restricting users to a particular list of programs

Tags: permissions, restricted-access

Is there any way to restrict users on Ubuntu similar to Desklock for windows? Basically, these are computers for systems control and I need to keep them from opening anything other than the controls software (through javaws) and possibly a browser. I've looked at rbash but I don't know how to, or if I even can, restrict GUI applications with it.

Comment: Have you tried just removing all applications you don't want users to open?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/541213/is-there-an-open-source-equivalent-of-windows-software-restriction-policies-for

Comment: @NerdOfCode That is an option if there's nothing else we can do, but it would be nice for administrators to have other programs when they use the machine.

Comment: You could always just change the file mode, using chmod on all the programs